# Using function-like marcos, any problems?

Tags: c, optimization

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

function-like macro are only text replacement, I know some programmers prefer inline functions. I am wondering if there is anything wrong with what I have done.

Just couple of points to note, I haven't used the do...while(0) or curly braces to wrap, as I would get a non-declared error for the isdn_channel.

```
#define ISDN_CHANNEL_GET(channel)                                       \
    module_isdn_channel_t *isdn_channel = NULL;                         \
    isdn_channel = channel->base.imp->isdn_channels[channel->isdn_id];  \
    if(!isdn_channel) {                                                 \
        LOG(CRITICAL, "Failed to get channel data");                    \
        return FALSE;                                                   \
    }
```

And in my source code I use it like this, without added the semi-colon:

```
ISDN_CHANNEL_GET(channel)
isdn_channel->base.sync_answer |= SIP_CONNECTED;
```

Everything works ok, but I just want to check as I just getting into writing these function-like macros.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Funny thing is going to happen when you write 1 line `if`, or `for` without `{}`, and the macro is that one line. There is a `do { code } while (0)` idiom to prevent such thing from happening.

Comment: should you be returning in that macro?  As you said, its a text replacement, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem as long as you don't do things like:
    if (condition)
    ISDN_CHANNEL_GET(channel)

Wrap your macro with a do... while(0) to avoid this problem.

Comment: +1, but the problem is not only in `if`/`else` constructs, but that already before in the example this violates the usual syntax expectation: something that looks like a function call should have the same syntactic rules as one. Not only editors suspect that the statement `ISDN_CHANNEL_GET` will extend on the next line but any casual reader will think the same. So your code really becomes hard to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Please dont use return in a macro.

As we know, that Macros tell the preprocessor to replace whatever is after the #define..

So u may unknowingly return in the middle of a function

Comment: I would return immediately if the data is NULL, as I can't carry on.

Comment: In that case, it is better to have the check seperately after calling the macro if(!isdn_channel)

Answer (score 2):

There are other problems here, after the ones mentioned by jbgs and Manimehalai:

- multiple evaluation of the macro parameter (here you use it twice)
- operator precedence (always use parenthesis around a parameter)
- lack of typing (use typing as much as you can, the compiler is your friend)

The first two are killers, as soon as you pass in more complicated expressions as arguments, that also possibly contain side effects. The third will byte you when you pass in a pointer to a structure that has fields of the same name, e.g, but that do something completely different.

Your example is really one where writing an `inline` function that has the same functionality is trivial. The compiler can help you a lot on debugging your code if you'd do that, always work with the compiler and not against it.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you `call` this function-like macro, it will get expanded - You optimize for time but not for space :-). It will certainly expand the size of your application when compiled.

My first law: "you can optimize for space or optimize for time - but not both space and time"